# error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for PropertyValueFactory<> Java

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 with this method:

```
private void setTable(){
        columnaID.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("id"));

        columnaNOMBRE.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("nombre"));

        columnaCORREO.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("correo"));

        columnaDIRECCION.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("direccion"));

        columnaTELEFONO.setCellFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<> ("telefono"));

        tablaCLIENTES.setItems(data);
}
```

But I get THW following error message:

[image]

I'm using JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0 and Java 8, everything on W10, I don't know if that matters

Comment: You must provide a type parameter for the generic `PropertyValueFactory<>` objects. Why do you expect the compiler to be able to infer the type?  You must show the source code for `PropertyValueFactory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `setCellFactory` when you mean `setCellValueFactory`. **Assuming the code you have omitted from the question is correct**, the following should compile:

```
private void setTable(){
    columnaID.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<> ("id"));

    columnaNOMBRE.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<> ("nombre"));

    columnaCORREO.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<> ("correo"));

    columnaDIRECCION.setCellFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<> ("direccion"));

    columnaTELEFONO.setCellFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<> ("telefono"));

    tablaCLIENTES.setItems(data);
}
```